# Can a file move itself in C?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, gnu

I'm trying to make a file install itself into the system (linux).

Every method I use (rename, system(mv), execl, etc) fails. Is there anyway to make a running executable move itself while running? The closest I've come is renaming it but only within the same directory.

Comment: This is why installer scripts are usually used.

Comment: Yes, on Linux, a program or script can move the file from which it was loaded. (The same is not generally true on Windows.)  There is no special trick.  If you present one of your attempts then we can speak to why it does not work, but as it stands, the question is too broad.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is it always guaranteed that the executable is fully loaded to the memory and there won't be any dynamic loading? Just curious.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The mappings are a link to the original file, so it won't be deleted off disk until the executable is unmapped when the process ends.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So what will happen if the executable is trying to delete/move itself?

Comment: If the file is "moved" within the same file system then it doesn't actually move at all -- it is just unlinked from one directory and linked to a different one.  If it is moved across file systems then its bytes are also copied, but the original is not removed from disk and does not become eligible for overwriting as long as any process has the file open.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Directories entries are merely links to inodes. The operating system’s mapping record also contains a link to the inode. The inode is what manages the actual file on disk; it contains information about where the blocks of the file are and so on. To move a file (within a file system) while it is open, it is merely necessary to add an entry in one directory that links to the inode and remove the entry from the old directory.

Comment: Thanks all, it makes sense. Sorry for hijacking the question, but hopefully this info will be beneficial to others too.

Comment: Usually Linux distributions will have a package manager to manage programs and their dependencies. Working around that is the best way to get a lot of hate, and In my opinion rightfully so.

Answer (score 0):

The code below "copies" itself to a new destination and gets deleted after termination. Basically, the code makes a new entry (hardlink) at the specified location and removes the current one (from the calling directory). The contents of the file will be preserved, since there is no copy and deletion involved.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{   
    //current filepath (dir + name)
    const char* file_path = argv[0];

    //extract filename component (needed to append to newdir)
    char* file_name_ = strdup(file_path);
    char* file_name = basename(file_name_);

    //make new path name
    char* new_dir = "<put your destination here - with no slash ('/') at the end>";
    size_t new_path_len = strlen(new_dir) + strlen(file_name) + 2; //two extra bytes: '/' + '\0'
    char new_path[new_path_len];
    snprintf(new_path, new_path_len, "%s/%s", new_dir, file_name);

    //make a new name for a file (hardlink)
    link(file_path, new_path);
    //delete a name and possibly the file it refers to
    unlink(file_path);

    //cleanup
    free(file_name_);

    return 0;
}
```

**Hint:** careful study of the documenation to `link` is highly recommended (especially the **ERRORS** section).

**References:**

[basename](https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) - parse pathname components
[link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) - make a new name for a file
[unlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) - delete a name and possibly the file it refers to